# Editing a model in the controller using bind deletes attributes not included in the bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The following code on a Controller is used to edit a Model `MyClass` with attributes `name, attr1, attr2, attr3, ... , attr10`. The bind `[Bind(Include = "ID,name,attr1,attr2")]` does not include most of the attributes, and it turns out those are cleared away after saving the changes to the database.

What I would like is the binded attributes to be updated but preserving the old values for the rest of the attributes without need to specifying them on the bind (because there are many and they change often). This is the complete Edit function code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,name,attr1,attr2")] MyClass item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

How can I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: Why are you using a Bind if you intend to bind all attributes of the `MyClass` type?  Just omit the `[Bind]` attribute.

Comment: I just want to edit name, attr1 and attr2. The rest should be left unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Erik's answer is technically correct, I think it is a bit of an anti-pattern.

First, when you're editing an entity, you should never just be passing the posted object directly off to the database to overwrite whatever is there.

Your edit action should take the id (or some other identifying value) as a param:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Foo model)
```

Then, you should pull the object fresh from the database and check that the thing being modified is the right thing and still exists:

```
var foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
if (foo == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Finally, you map the values that should be modified from the posted data onto the entity from the database:

```
foo.name = model.name;
// etc.
```

Now, when you save, only the values you intended to be modified will be modified and there's no need to explicitly tamper with the change tracking.

Comment: ok, isn't there a smarter way that does that based on the properties listed on the bind annotation so that there is no need to go one by one?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to wire your Entity to your form.  You would be better following Chris's advice here and wiring up a View Model to your Entity via some sort of Mapping utility either manually or via http://automapper.org/

Comment: Well, mapping kind of necessitates going property by property by nature. Even in Erik's answer, you would have to manually set each property's modified status. A view model, in general, is a superior approach to using `Bind`, but it still doesn't solve the issue of mapping the values back to your entity. Using an automated mapping library like AutoMapper is one way you can simplify some of the logic. However, the author of that library himself says that it is not and never was intended to map *to* an entity, only *from*.

Answer (score 2):

First it's important to understand why you are losing those values.  So lets take a look at [`EntityState.Modified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx).

> One of the scalar properties on the object was modified and the SaveChanges method has not been called. In POCO entities without change-tracking proxies, **the state of the modified properties changes to Modified** when the DetectChanges method is called. After the changes are saved, the object state changes to Unchanged.

Since your object is not retrieved from the database (it's not in the context), all properties are modified, thus saving the object to the database, saves all properties.

Instead of marking the entire object changed, you'll only want to mark specific properties as changed:

```
db.Users.Attach(item);
db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.ID).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.name).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.att1).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.att2).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

(If your `ID` is the Key, don't mark it as modified)